# Rotating image using gestures after flipping is not working in winjs

Tags: css, windows-8, winjs, css-transforms

I first flipped an image and then rotated the image using gestures but the image is rotating in the opposite direction.

This is the code i used to flip the image

```
 tempob.style.transform = m.scale(-1, 1, 1);// Horizontal flip
 tempob.style.transform = m.scale(1, -1, 1);// vertical flip
```

Image rotates properly when not flipped while using gesture.

This is the code i used for manipulating gestures

```
  elt.style.transform = m.translate(e.offsetX, e.offsetY).
                        translate(e.translationX, e.translationY).
                        rotate(e.rotation * 180 / Math.PI).
                        scale(e.scale).
                        translate(-e.offsetX, -e.offsetY);
```

This code works properly according to the gestures when image is not flipped.

Thanks in advance